# Where to outlet the water that comes from storm drain and gutters, to prevent soil/roots getting into pipe?

Tags: drainage, downspout

In my house, currently, all the water that comes from gutters and storm drains goes into one main underground 4-inch PVC pipe that outlets at the end of my backyard, right into under the soil, at 1-1/2 feet deep.

I spent a lot of time yesterday removing a clog at the end of the pipe (see picture). Basically, the mix of tree roots and soil, clogged the end of the pipe and prevented water from storm drain/gutters to flow properly.

[image]

Right now the end of the pipe is just buried underground, and my question is:

Given the fact that I don't have access to street disposal (unless I pump it all the way up more than 200 feet), and my backyard is mainly soil, what is the best way to dispose of the water? I don't want to just leave it how it is, because I'm concerned it will be clogged again. How one chooses between building a dry well, a pop-up drainage, cover the end of the pipe with some type of mash, etc?

Comment: What do you do in dry season, use sprinklers ?

Comment: No - I don't maintain the grass. Planning to get rid of it.

Comment: the reason I am asking is, do you want to use that relatively good water for your yard, if so capture it in dry well then pump it out when needed.

Comment: pop-up drainage would work, by holding water back in the pipe until overflow, adding mesh would work only preventing roots going in to the pipe. Distribution would be another option, by installing 2 inch lines on either site and leading it away, thus distributing water

Comment: Thanks, Ruskes. Do you want to answer so I can accept it (vs comment)?

Comment: add a bunch of river rocks around the end of the pipe to keep plants at bay and make cleaning out next time a lot easier. a mini rain garden. you might also want to add and cap a Y about a yard from the end of the pipe so that you can easily ram it out in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I'd dig a rock pit surrounded with landscape fabric for it to empty into.

I'd also put two Ys with risers, one going towards the house and one towards the rock pit and cleanouts so that if it clogs in the future you can just use a root grinder or snake to clean it out in both directions (cheap insurance).

How big you make the rock pit is a harder question and depends on your rainfall, the area this is draining to and your soil type.

Comment: They make PVC "mesh" caps that can go on the pipe to keep the larger critters from making nests in the end. You could hold mosquito netting over the end of the pipe then screw the cap on to keep the small critters out, too, while still being able to easily remove it for clean out purposes.

Answer (score 0):

pop-up drainage would work, by holding water back in the pipe until overflow,

adding mesh would work only preventing roots going in to the pipe.

Distribution would be another option, by installing 2 inch lines on either site and leading it away, thus distributing water